# Using tuples in conditional breakpoints in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, f#, conditional-breakpoint

Will this be possible? In F# or C#? Both?

For example, I would like to set a conditional breakpoint in a F# program like that:

```
[x] Condition:

    myTuple == (3,3)

(o) Is true
(_) Has changed
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This condition

```
System.Tuple.Create(3,3).Equals(myTuple)
```

seems to work for me.

(Note that F# uses the C# expression evaluator in the debugger, which means breakpoint conditions, immediate window, etc, must use C# syntax, not F# syntax, when debugging F# code.  In this instance, however, the same code above is correct in both F# and C#.)